# PHP/HTML dynamic page/search

Tags: php, html, css

I'm finding it hard to get my head around the logic around this issue I'm having.

Currently, I have a search.html page that on submit goes to Results.php. There is then some code that searches the mysql for whatever was inputted into the search page.

Now, How would I go about having the search and the results on the same page? How would i return the variable from the search page? For example before I was using;

```
$search_term = $_POST['name'];
```

How would I get the 'name' variable if its on the same page?

EDIT: Second issue

I have the code working that many of you answered with, thank you very much! I've now come to my second problem. I have two inputs a textbox for the search query and then a dropdown box for a subject to search.

Then user then presses submit and the db is searched, this all works fine. I now want to create another dropdown box so the user can sort the provided results in a matter that they see fitting, for example price high to low etc.

I have the HTML code already done but as you can imagine, the second I press submit its reloading the page and as it doesn't know what the user has previously searched it exits the php and acts as if its a fresh page load.

URL: http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0862025/db/test.php

Play around with it, press submit to lift all products in the database.

Comment: not recommended for results pages. It's OK to post to same page for inserts and updates, then redirect to the same page again with the post set. But on results pages where the post is submitted you can't refresh the page. You will be prompted to submit post again. annoying for end user.

Comment: @matt - post, get redirect - http://www.andypemberton.com/engineering/the-post-redirect-get-pattern/ - but in general, searches should employ get. post is encouraged to be used when changes are to be made. Not necessarily for a simple read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make the whole thing in one file. This is crude and totally incomplete, but something like this -

```
<?php
$results = array();
$term = "";

if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $term = $_POST['name'];
    $order_by = "";

    if(isset($_POST['order'])
    {
        switch($_POST['order'])
        {
            case "price-high-low":
                $order_by = "ORDER BY `price` DESC";
            break;
            case "name":
                $order_by = "ORDER BY `name` ASC";
            break;
            default:
                $order_by = "ORDER BY `id` DESC";
            break;
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%". sanitized($_POST['name']) ."%' $order_by";

    //run query and assign the results to a variable, like $results
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $term; ?>"><br>
    <?php if(!empty($results)): ?>
    <select name="order">
        <option value="price-high-low">Price: High to Low</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
    </select>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php if(!empty($results)): ?>
Results for term: <?php echo $term; ?><br>
<?php foreach($results AS $res): ?>
    <?php echo $res['name']; ?><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Of course this is very crude and assumes many things. Like that your results are an array, for one. That your results have a key called name, etc.

But as you asked, this is all on one page and that's the basic idea.

feel free to ask any questions and I may update as needed.

** UPDATE 1 **
I updated this example to consider a dropdown that only shows after a result is made. It will re-submit the form with an added order parameter. This example does not consider pagination and makes the assumption that you have a sanitize function that cleans the input. Obviously you should be using mysqli or PDO as they will both offer solutions for this. Do NOT rely on mysql_ functions like mysql_real_escape_string. All mysql_ is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the code, Kai Qing, Just after I posted this question I tired the code myself using the $_POST code and it worked perfect. Just had to add the "exit" function so the page didn't error when it was first run. I do have another question though, that might take some explaining, do you have a personal email I can contact you on? Or should i just put it here?

Comment: you can just add it to your question. click edit and add it to the bottom, then comment in my answer to notify me

Comment: I have updated. This assumes you are using the code as close to the above as possible. It simply adds a select menu if there are results and on submit should re-submit the whole form basically creating a new query.

Comment: I'm struggling to apply your example to mine, yours appears to use array as the key for checking against, I don't use this as I'm using PDO as required by the assignment. This is the code I have right now, please excuse how horrible it is. http://pastebin.com/6K8CZCe8

Comment: Using connection factory you may have to refer to their docs. I use PDO with standard written queries so I'm not sure how to apply this. I assume this is what you're using: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4074-PHP-Manage-database-connections-using-PDO-extension.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know connectionfactory already existed, I just picked a random name for it, The class is something I made myself; http://pastebin.com/kvURp1Zj

Comment: If you can see anywhere else where my code could be improved is bits I'm doing completely wrong please let me know. I'm still extremely knew to web development, having come from a games programming background, So I don't yet know the correct ways to do things

Comment: Based on your connection class it looks like you already have the option to pass $order to the select method. Why not use that? just pass a string like "`title` DESC" to the select method and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way. Only difference is that you will have to check if the form was submitted

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // do your search here
    // and show the results
}
```

And obviously the form action has to point on the site itself. That's best done with leaving it empty:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax call to make query from mysql and display results on the same page. A good example is at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your form and php code in the same page. Give your submit button a "name".
Let's say we have *search.php:*

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="search_button" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['search_button'])) {
    $search_term = $_POST['name'];
    //DB query here
    //echo the result you get from query
}
?>
```